# Simplifying non-boolean expressions in Z3 assuming a set of axioms

Tags: z3

Is there a way to simplify non-boolean expressions in Z3 assuming a set of axioms?

For example, I would like to assert that "a==b", and then simplify the expression
"If(a == b, 1, 2)" to get "1".

In particular, I'm interested in working with array theory:

> ```
> I = BitVecSort(32)
> A = Array('A', I, I)
> a = BitVec('a',32)
> b = BitVec('b',32)
> c = BitVec('c',32)
> ...
> A2 = Store(A, a, 1) 
> A3 = Store(A2, b, 2) 
> A4 = Store(A3, c, 3)
>
> simplify_assuming(A4[a], Distinct(a, b, c))
> ```

This should return "1", since the Select expression can be simplified to "1" assuming all the indexes are distinct, according to the array theory rules.

I've tried to use the "ctx-solver-simplify" tactic, but it seems to only work for boolean expressions. Is there some other way to simplify non-boolean expressions, or somehow tell the array rewriter that the indexes are distinct?

Thanks.

Comment: "I've tried to use the "ctx-solver-simplify" tactic,
 but it seems to only work for boolean expressions."

That is correct. the ctx-solver-simplify routine does not walk under non-Boolean terms. 
The algorithm used by this simplifier could be generalized to walk under non-Boolean terms, 
but I was not anticipating an application for this. It makes use of the assumption that 
it simplifies Boolean expressions in some number of places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nikolaj described in the comment above, `ctx-solver-simplify` will not walk under non-Boolean expressions. Another option is to use the tactic `solve-eqs` that will use asserted equalities to rewrite the rest of the formula. For example, given the equality `a == b`, Z3 will replace every occurrence of `b` with `a` (or vice-versa). After that, `if(a == b, 1, 2)` will be rewritten to `1`.

However, `solve-eqs` will not use disequalities such as `Distinct(a, b, c)`. Another option is to use the tactic `propagate-values`. It replaces every occurrence of an assertion `P` with `true`. Similarly, if we have an assertion `not P`, it will replace every other occurrence of `P` with `false`. 
This tactic is essentially performing unit Boolean propagation. Moreover, it is meant to be fast, and will not apply any form of theory reasoning. Example, if we have `Distinct(a, b, c)`, it will not replace `a == b` with `false`. So, this approach may be too fragile for your purposes.
Here is a script that uses it. It is also available online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/kt7). In this script, I wrap the expression `A4[a]` using a fresh predicate `P` because a Z3 Goal is a set of Boolean formulas.
I use `blast_distinct` to convert the `Distinct` into a sequence of disequalities, and `expand_select_store` to expand a term of the form `store(A, i, v)[j]` into an `if-then-else` of the form `if(i == j, v, A[j])`. Note that, the result contains `P(1)` that indicates that `P(A4[a])` was simplified to `1`.

```py
I = BitVecSort(32)
A = Array('A', I, I)
a = BitVec('a',32)
b = BitVec('b',32)
c = BitVec('c',32)
A2 = Store(A, a, 1) 
A3 = Store(A2, b, 2) 
A4 = Store(A3, c, 3)

P = Function('P', I, BoolSort())
G = Goal()
G.add(P(A4[a]))
G.add(Distinct(c, b, a))

T = Then(With("simplify", blast_distinct=True, expand_select_store=True), "propagate-values")
print(T(G))
```